# My website searches for data in heavy databases. Should I use Lucene to search or write my own algorithm?

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm, lucene

I am writing a website which indexes large amounts of data into databases (each with about 800 tables per database), and the website allows you to search the database for various items. Should I use something like lucene or just write my own search algorithm? I am using PHP and MySQL. Although I can filter my SELECT queries, and create a searching algorithm I just wanted to know if I should use Lucene because I am just indexing stuff in a database. Also please do suggest anything that might help me. Forgot to mention that even though I have 800 tables they would be pretty small in size.

Comment: Are you talking about Zend_Search_Lucene or the Java implementation? There are also alternatives based on Lucene providing more complete solutions. Either way, you should clarify the types of searches you want to perform.

Comment: Even without knowing your data set, I can say with 99% certainty that writing your own search algorithm is the wrong path.

Comment: Can you provide some technical details please? Without Lucene, what would you do? How would you use Lucene? What's in the database? How are they searching? How do you know you need a full text search engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucene is a mature, tested, open source library.

I would definetly say: try to use it as much as possible, it will probably be better and consume less time then implementing your own library.

If there is a certain functionality that lucene does not provide - you can always create your own variation of lucene to take care of it.

Do not underestimate the importance of the community in using products such lucene: Help is almost always available in lucene's forums [and SO], and the library is constantly tested and maintained because of the large number of users!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data answering this question is very hard, however I can say from personal experience that writing a search of any kind quickly becomes very complex. You have to worry about weighting the various columns you are searching, and search in SQL is almost never as fast as search in a dedicated search engine. At work we are switching from an in house SQL based search to Sphinx Search to search our product catalog because of this very reason.